# XcodeのViewController

Tags: xcode

お世話になります。
Xcode でSingle View Application を選択してプロジェクトを作りたいと思っております。
`View.controller.swift`の`viewDidLoad()`に例えば`print("ありがとう")`と書くと、Run した時、
出力ウィンドウが開いて、`ありがとう` と表示されているはずですが、何も表示されません。
お忙しい、とおもいますが、ご指導、宜しく、お願いします。
Xcode 8.2.1  macOS Sierra 10.12.3 です。

Comment: 今回のケースで「ありがとう」という文字が表示されるのは、Xcodeのデバッグエリアではないでしょうか？デバッグエリアとはソースコードの下の左側にシンボルとその値が表示され、右側に出力とデバッガーコマンドを打ち込んでその結果が出力されるエリアの事です

Answer (score 1):

ご質問の内容だけからは十分わからないのですが、明示的にxcodeタグを使用されているので、Xcodeそのものの使い方に関するご質問だと理解させていただきます。

Xcodeからアプリを実行した場合、アプリ内の`print`等で出力した内容はデバッグエリア中のデバッグコンソールに出力されます。「出力ウィンドウが開いて」と表現されると、何か新しいウインドウが開くことを期待しているように読めますが、画面下部に(標準状態では)小さくデバッグ用の領域(デバッグエリア)が現れて、その右半分のデバッグコンソールに出力されるだけです。

[image: デバッグコンソール]

まれに、自分でデバッグエリアを閉じた後などに、そのデバッグエリアさえ現れないことがありますが、その場合はXcodeのウインドウ右上にあるボタンを操作してデバッグエリアを直接開くよう操作してください。

[image: Show/Hide Switch]

---

お尋ねになりたい事柄が何か別の部分にあるのでしたら、その状況をもう少し詳しく正確に(*1)表すようにご質問内容を編集してください。

*1 例えばSingle View Applicationを使用して作成されたプロジェクトならば、ファイル名は`View.controller.swift`ではなく、`ViewController.swift`のはずです。プログラミングでは、たった１文字の違い(大文字小文字だけの違いを含めて)で全く異なる結果になることがよくあるので、可能なかぎり正確に記載するように心がけられた方が良いでしょう。